# NHibernate + .NETFramework 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nhibernate

Alguém saberia dizer qual a última versão do Nhibernate que funciona em .NET 3.5? Eu cheguei a procurar no próprio site, mas não consegui encontrar. A que eu possuo é a 2.1.0.4000.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que vi, a ultima versão para framework 3.5 ficou na 5.0.0 (não há dependência com frameworks).

Qualquer dúvida pode dar uma olhada aqui no github deles também: [github nHibernate](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/master/LICENSE.txt)